# Set breakpoint by sourcefile in Delve

Tags: go, delve

How can I set a breakpoint by sourcefile?
I have the following code in a tmp.go file.

```
package main

func main() {
   a, b := 1, 2
   c := a + b
   println(c)
```

}

This works

```
$ dlv debug ./tmp.go
(dlv) b main.main:1
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x105395d for main.main() ./tmp.go:4
```

But this fails

```
$ dlv debug ./tmp.go
(dlv) b ./tmp.go:4
Command failed: Location "./tmp.go:4" not found
```

Edit:
This works

```
$ dlv debug ./tmp.go
(dlv) b tmp.go:4
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x105395d for main.main() ./tmp.go:4
```

Any ideas what might be wrong with my environment?

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas what might be wrong with my environment?

---

> Why should this question be closed?
>
> off-topic because...
>
> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

You didn't provide an MCVE, so we can only guess.

We have no idea what is in your `main.go`, so how do you expect us to know what your problem is?

---

For example, just a guess, with an MCVE,

`main.go`:

```
package main

func main() {
    a, b := 1, 2
    c := a + b
    println(c)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/i2D9uZnFlXn

Output:

```
$ go run main.go
3
$ dlv debug ./main.go
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) break main.main:4
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x454bda for main.main() ./main.go:7
(dlv) quit
$ dlv debug ./main.go
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) break main.go:4
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x454b9d for main.main() ./main.go:4
(dlv) quit
$
```

`break main.main:4` and `break main.go:4` are not the same thing, at `./main.go:7` and at `./main.go:4` respectively. Line numbers are relative to files, functions, etc.

---

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I update the question to use your example.